# Returning a multiple table LINQ query as one object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, repository, relational-database

So for my current application I need to query a database using a repository that returns a single object. The problem is that the information is split into two different tables. The object im trying to get is a Rule object. The rule class consists of the following database entities:

```
class Rule
    {
        STRATRULEDEF ruleDefinition { get; set; }
        List<STRATCODE> ruleCodeList { get; set; }
```

In my repository im using the following query to get the relevant info:

```
public void GetRule(int ruleKey)
        {
            Rule ruleQuery = from ruleDefinition in AREContext.STRATRULEDEFs
                            from ruleCodes in AREContext.STRATCODES
                            where ruleDefinition.STRATRULEKEY == ruleKey 
                                  && ruleCodes.STRATRULEKEY == ruleKey
                            select new { ruleDefinition, ruleCodes };
```

So I have two problems.

1) How do I return the ruleQuery back as a 'Rule' object, if I change 'var' to rule I get the following error:

Error  10  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'TestRules.Rule'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Can I cast System.Linq.IQueryable to TestRules.Rule?

2) My tables have a one to many relationship so the query should return one ruleDef record and multiple ruleCode records, however at the moment I get multiple ruleDef records that exist as duplicates of each other. Any ideas?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize a `Rule` object and you can use `FirstOrDefault` if you want a single object:

```
IEnumerable<Rule> rules = from ruleDefinition in AREContext.STRATRULEDEFs
                          from ruleCodes in AREContext.STRATCODES
                          where ruleDefinition.STRATRULEKEY == ruleKey 
                             && ruleCodes.STRATRULEKEY == ruleKey
                          select new Rule
                          { 
                              ruleDefinition = ruleDefinition, 
                              ruleCodeList = ruleCodes.ToList()
                          };
Rule firstRule = rules.FirstOrDefault();  // can be null if rules is empty
```

Comment: Trying your appraoch I got a similar error  Error 10 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestRules.Rule>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Entity Framework. Try to add `AsEnumerable()` to the first two lines to  force  to run using LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Because you tagged EntityFramework, you have another option here for loading data hierarchically.

Assuming that you have navigation properties between the two, such as a foreign key on ruleDefinition to a collection of ruleCodes, you should be able to do something like

```
AREContext.STRATRULEDEFs.Include(s => s.STRATCodes).ToList;
```

Which would return to you a list of your STRATRULEDEFs objects, each with a property to a loaded collection of STRATCODES. From here, mapping to alternative classes can be achieved trivially manually, or through use of a mapping plugin.

Take note, Include is an extension method, so be sure to add the following to your file.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```